# Understanding CGRectDivide()

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to experiment with `UIViews` on screen and using pan gestures. So I got some open source code from another project that I am looking at - and trying to learn a few things from it.

```
-(BOOL)isPointContainedWithinBezelRect:(CGPoint)point {
    CGRect leftBezelRect;
    CGRect tempRect;
    CGFloat bezelWidth = 20;

    CGRectDivide(self.view.bounds, &leftBezelRect, &tempRect, bezelWidth, CGRectMinXEdge);

    return CGRectContainsPoint(leftBezelRect, point);
}
```

I understand that `CGRectDivide` function "Slices up a rect", but thats as far as I can make out.

I hope to get more clarification regarding the function. Also, how does the function return value vide a false / true value?

Comment: I have. Its a little verbose for me. I understand that CGRectDevide "Slices up a rect" - but thats as far as I can make out.

Comment: It is interesting that you got stuck on the CGRectContainsPoint rather than the CGRectDivide.

Comment: I was actually stuck on both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGRectDivide
and
http://nshipster.com/cggeometry/

But it seems that this method could be simplified to

```
-(BOOL)isPointContainedWithinBezelRect:(CGPoint)point {
    CGRect leftBezelRect = self.view.bounds;
    leftBezelRect.size.width = 20;
    return CGRectContainsPoint(leftBezelRect, point);
}
```

or even to

```
-(BOOL)isPointContainedWithinBezelRect:(CGPoint)point {
    return CGRectContainsPoint(self.view.bounds, point) && (point.x <= 20);
}
```

Comment: Simplifying it helped. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
void CGRectDivide(
  CGRect rect,
  CGRect *slice,
  CGRect *remainder,
  CGFloat amount,
  CGRectEdge edge
)
```

The CGRectDivide method splits a CGRect into two CGRects based on the `CGRectEdge` and distance from the rectangle side `amount` provided to the method.

[image]

[Source](http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/torrey-betts/archive/2013/05/28/quick-tip-dividing-a-cgrect-using-cgrectdivide-objective-c.aspx)